# gitlab ci redis as dependency service

Tags: php, redis, gitlab-ci

I want to use Redis service as a dependency of my PHP/Nginx (Symfony application) application on GitlabCI and it should use the custom port.
I already have Postgres added like this (I'll show just pieces of configurations):

```
variables:
    # POSTGRES - Use the values from the .env.test file.
    POSTGRES_DB: offers_test
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: asdfasdf

services:
    -   name: postgres:10
        # "postgresql" is what we use in the .env.test file
        alias: postgresql
```

here all is okay b-z Postgres image has a list of supported env variables and I can use them to configure Postgres connection.

But for Redis, I can't find any good image where I can configure a custom connection data. I only found official Gitlab documentation on how to use Redis service https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/redis.html. So I add Redis to services

```
services:
    - redis:latest
```

And images built successfully, but on my tests, I'm getting the error like 
`Error connecting to redis. Connection refused` it's because CI connecting to Redis with default port, but I'm using a custom port. Any idea of how I can override connection details of Redis service?